# AngularJS: How to display a list of images (via Drag and Drop)

Tags: angularjs

i was wondering how to display a list of images (via drag an drop). I already have the directive for the drag an drop part. **But where in my app do i "parse" the FileList and how do i pass the data from the directive to the partial?** Is this the job ob the controller?

```
/**
 * Adds drag&drop functionality to a div
 * @Example: <div drop-target ng-class="{active:isHot}" class="dropzone">Drop here</div>
 */
angular.module('myApp.directives').
    directive('dropTarget', function () {
        return function ($scope, $element) {

            // Drophandler passes a fileList to the controller
            $element.bind('drop', function (evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();

                // FileList should go to the controller/view
                var fileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;
                console.log(fileList);

                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.imageList = fileList;
                });

                return false;
            });

            // DragOverHandler highlights the dropzone
            $element.bind('dragover', function (evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();

                $scope.isHot = true;

                return evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
            });

            // DragOverHandler de-highlights the dropzone
            $element.bind('dragleave', function (evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();

                $scope.isHot = false;
            });
        };
    })
```

Comment: Could you let us know which variable in the above code contains the list of files that have been dragged and dropped? Is it `fileList`?

Comment: Then why have you not bound it to `$scope`? It is a local variable...

Comment: Sry. I am new to AngularJS an scopes might be wrong. That's why i am asking. I dont know where to go from here…

Comment: You could try providing a fiddle / plunker for your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `fileList` variable contains the files that have been dragged and dropped, that is, taking the following line as reference:

```
// FileList should go to the controller/view
var fileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;
```

...you simply change the `fileList` variable to a scope variable instead of a local variable.
Thus the above code would then read

```
$scope.fileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;
```

You don't need the `$scope.$apply()` function that follows the above code. Instead, your files  should already be present in `$scope.fileList`. Use can then use this variable in the view that holds the `drop-target` directive.

Comment: Thanks, But I want to use fileList outside the drop-target directive.

Comment: @fabian I think you should be able to use it outside the directive considering that your directive is not creating a new scope...